# USB-to-Parallel adapter rated as USB 1.1 - will its driver lower speed of USB 2.0 bus?

Tags: usb, drivers, speed, hub, parallel-port

I need to connect a printer with a parallel port to a computer with only a USB 2.0 bus.

I'd like to do so without lowering the USB 2.0 bus speed to USB 1.1.

All the USB-to-Parallel adapter cable found so far seem to be rated as USB 1.1 and they come with a CD which presumably contains a necessary driver.

I haven't purchased one and tested it out yet, but if so, would the cable's driver lower speed of USB 2.0 bus?

Answer (score 2):

The [parallel port specification itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1284) is the limiting factor here; the fastest it can go in ECP mode is 2.5 MByte/s, which is somewhat faster than USB 1.1's maximum speed but much slower than USB 2.0. So even if you find a parallel port adapter that can do ECP (and your printer can do it as well) and USB 2.0, it won't be much faster than USB 1.1

Comment: i don't think that's exactly what is being asked.  the question sounds like the OP's concerned with the effect of using a USB 1.1 device on a USB 2.0 bus -- ie, will other devices on the same hub experience speed drops because of this USB 1.1 device.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm concerned with. It's not an issue of the print speed, but of the possibility of a USB 1.1 driver for the USB-to-parallel cable slowing down the entire USB 2.0 bus.

Comment: @cumminjm: I see. No, that should not be a problem - especially if you connect it directly to the PC, since each USB port is usually a completely independant host. But it should even be possible to mix USB 1 and 2 devices on an USB 2 hub without adverse effects.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't lower the speed of the USB bus.  Each device reports to the hub its speed, and the USB hub is responsible for communicating with each device at its proper speed.  Also, as @Michael said, each internal port is effectively an independent root hub.